# How to use Intent in RecyclerViewAdapter with Cardview

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

Please help i need to create an intent for cardview but i'm unable to use Intent in RecyclerViewAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,List<Cards> items, int itemLayout)
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.items = items;
        this.itemLayout= itemLayout;
    }
...
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, YOUR_ACTIVITY.class);
mContext.startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to use intent you need a context.
In Constuct you can pass one.

```
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,List<Cards> items, int itemLayout)
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.items = items;
        this.itemLayout= itemLayout;
    }
```

Now you have context in your adapter. So you can

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, YOUR_ACTIVITY.class);
mContext.startActivity(intent)
```